# destination:isActive:label deprecated in iOS 16 - I need help migrating

Tags: swiftui, ios16

I need help migrating my code for iOS 16 support:

```
//
//  RegistrationView.swift
//  Recosia
//
//  Created by Alex Slater on 16/11/2022.
//

import SwiftUI

struct RegistrationView: View {
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var fullname = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    @State var root = [Root]()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            NavigationStack(root: $root) {
                //content
                .onChange(of: viewModel.didAuthenticateUser) { newValue in
                    guard newValue else {return}
                    root.append(.profile)
                }.navigationDestination(for: Root.self) { navigation in
                    switch navigation {
                        case .profile:
                            ProfilePhotoSelectorView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
//            NavigationLink(destination: ProfilePhotoSelectorView(),
//                           isActive: $viewModel.didAuthenticateUser,
//                           label: { })
            
            AuthHeaderView(title1: "Sign up", title2: "to Recosia")
            
            VStack(spacing: 40) {
                    CustomInputField(imageName: "at.circle.fill", placeholderText: "Username", text: $username)
                    
                    CustomInputField(imageName: "person", placeholderText: "Full Name", text: $fullname)
                    CustomInputField(imageName: "envelope", placeholderText: "Email", text: $email)
                    
                CustomInputField(imageName: "lock",
                                 placeholderText: "Password",
                                 isSecureField: true,
                                 text: $password)
                
            }
            .padding(32)
            
            Button {
                viewModel.register(withEmail: email,
                                   password: password,
                                   fullname: fullname,
                                   username: username)
            } label: {
                Text("Create Account")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(width: 340, height: 50)
                    .background(Color(.systemPink))
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .padding()
                    
            }
            .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.5), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Text("Already have an account?")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.black))
                    
                    Text("Sign In")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.systemPink))
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 32)
            }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }

struct RegistrationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RegistrationView()
    }
}

enum Root {
    case profile
}
```

with the error:

> init(destination:isActive:label:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: use
> NavigationLink(value:label:) inside a NavigationStack or
> NavigationSplitView

I have tried re-arranging my code but I'm getting confused, can someone help!

Much appreciated :)

I tried using a `NavigationStack` with a `.navigationDestination`, but it says that it expects other arguments but the code presented above is all I have.

Answer (score 1):

The new [`NavigationLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink) no longer requires a destination `View`. However, it needs some kind of an identifier, so [`navigationDestination`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/navigationdestination(for:destination:)) expects the type of the identifier used in order to identify what `View` should be presented.

In your case, you don't need a `NavigationLink` anymore since you are navigating based on `viewModel.didAuthenticateUser`. You can listen to `didAuthenticateUser` and directly append the identifier to an array that you provide the `NavigationStack` with. Check [`init(path:root:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack/init(path:root:)-3bt4q?changes=l_8):

```
struct RegistrationView: View {
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var fullname = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    @State var root = [Root]()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $root) {
            VStack {
                AuthHeaderView(title1: "Sign up", title2: "to Recosia")
                
                VStack(spacing: 40) {
                    CustomInputField(imageName: "at.circle.fill", placeholderText: "Username", text: $username)
                    
                    CustomInputField(imageName: "person", placeholderText: "Full Name", text: $fullname)
                    CustomInputField(imageName: "envelope", placeholderText: "Email", text: $email)
                    
                    CustomInputField(imageName: "lock",
                                     placeholderText: "Password",
                                     isSecureField: true,
                                     text: $password)
                    
                }
                .padding(32)
                
                Button {
                    viewModel.register(withEmail: email,
                                       password: password,
                                       fullname: fullname,
                                       username: username)
                } label: {
                    Text("Create Account")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 340, height: 50)
                        .background(Color(.systemPink))
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                        .padding()
                    
                }
                .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.5), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Already have an account?")
                            .font(.caption)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.black))
                        
                        Text("Sign In")
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.systemPink))
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom, 32)
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .onChange(of: viewModel.didAuthenticateUser) { newValue in
                guard newValue else {return}
                root.append(.profile)
            }.navigationDestination(for: Root.self) { navigation in
                switch navigation {
                    case .profile:
                        ProfilePhotoSelectorView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    enum Root {
        case profile
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still having a couple of issues, the main one is that it can't find Root in scope.
I tried copy pasting the declaration from the apple docs but the issue still persists

Comment: Do you mean `Root` as in the enum with a capital R?

Comment: that brings up th error "Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'"

Comment: Could you edit your question to show your new code?

Comment: Of course Timmy, edited.

Comment: It appears you have an extra `}` just before `AuthHeaderView`

Comment: Well I'm getting the errors: 

- Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<[Root]>' to expected argument type '() -> Root'

- Generic parameter 'Root' could not be inferred

- Incorrect argument label in call (have 'root:_:', expected 'path:root:')

- Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'Binding<NavigationPath>' that does not accept a closure

Comment: My bad, I mistakenly swaped path & root. Edited my answer!

Comment: Thank you! - All errors gone apart from a new error: Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'onChange'

Comment: About that, you should replace `//content` with your `VStack` & its contents

Comment: The only contents in the vstack were the navigation stack - so would I just move the empty vstack under the navigation stack and take in the navigationstack contents?

Comment: Updated my answer! I added the full `View`

Comment: my bad - sorted now. Thanks for everything :)